# Crash on rendering pdf page in CA Tiled layer

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am trying to render pdf pages on `CGContext` by converting them into images and then rendering them in tiled layer. The application runs well on simulator but crashes on device for particular pdf page. On running the app on istruments, it seems to consume a lot of memory.

There have been many questions on this before on this platform and have tried all the solution but the problem persists. Please find the code below. It always crashes on calling `CGContextDrawPDFPage`

```
 CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);
    pdfScale = self.frame.size.width/pageRect.size.width;
    originalPdfScale = 2 * pdfScale;
    //pdfScale = 1.39444;
    pageRect.size = CGSizeMake(pageRect.size.width*pdfScale, pageRect.size.height*pdfScale);


    //---Create a low res image representation of the PDF page to display before the TiledPDFView renders its content---
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageRect.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //---First fill the background with white---
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context,pageRect);
    NSLog(@"context = %@ :::: pdfScale = %f ::::: page=%@ ", context, pdfScale, page );
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    //---Flip the context so that the PDF page is rendered right side up---
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, pageRect.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    //---Scale the context so that the PDF page is rendered at the correct size for the zoom level---
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, pdfScale,pdfScale);  
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh); 
    CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentDefault); 
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    UIImage *backgroundImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if (backgroundImageView) {
        [backgroundImageView removeFromSuperview];
        [backgroundImageView release];
        backgroundImageView = nil;
    }
    backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];
    backgroundImageView.frame = pageRect;
    backgroundImageView.userInteractionEnabled =YES;
    backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [self addSubview:backgroundImageView];
    [self sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImageView];


    // Create the TiledPDFView based on the size of the PDF page and scale it to fit the view.
    if (pdfView) {
        [pdfView removeFromSuperview];
        [pdfView release];
        pdfView = nil;
    }
    pdfView = [[ProM_TiledPDFView alloc] initWithFrame:pageRect andScale:pdfScale];
    [pdfView setPage:page];

    [self addSubview:pdfView];
    [backgroundImage release];
```

Comment: By the way, for anyone else looking at this question... the place where this source code comes from is [Apple's ZoomingPDFViewer sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Listings/Classes_PDFScrollView_m.html)

Comment: Also, CKK... what is the "particular PDF page" that this crashes on? Can you provide a file or URL that demonstrates the problem?